# FlashDevelop Configuration Issue - demands Java 1.6

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-7, flash-builder, flashdevelop, java-6

I've been using Flashdevelop (version 4.4) for some time now with zero problems.  I recently reinstalled Windows 7 however, and after installing Flashdevelop it is demanding Java 1.6 and won't compile without it.  Let me be more specific, here is the error I get when I try to compile a simple HelloWorld-type test:

```
"Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\Users\marc\Documents\DeleteMe\DeleteMe\DeleteMe.as3proj" -ipc 01be003c-6cb5-4d0b-9c35-c59dd2ea7a19 -version "4.6.0; 3.3" -compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34"
Building DeleteMe
mxmlc -load-config+=obj\DeleteMeConfig.xml -debug=true -incremental=true -swf-version=16 -o obj\DeleteMe634829909556672047
Starting java as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\java.exe;\bin\java.exe
Unable to start java.exe: The system cannot find the file specified
Could not compile because the fcsh process could not be started.
Build halted with errors (fcsh).
INITIALIZING: Failed, unable to run compiler
Done(1)"
```

The `GlobalClasspath` setting for the Java 1.6 JDK is set to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin`

I have also set my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the same location as well.  Might I be neglecting to set another environment variable?

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question, but have you installed java?

Comment: You could try to place the question on the forums of flashdevelop.org, since this a nice active community.

Comment: My guess is the `PATH` system variable doesn't contain the path to Java's bin directory (be it the JRE or JDK, since it's java.exe not running). Can you test by starting a CommandPrompt and typing `java -version ` ? If you don't see the Java version printed set the Windows Environment Variables and add the Java bin directory to `PATH`

Comment: you got it - thank you!  Don't I feel like a fool...  It's so rarely I do reinstalls, I neglected to set the PATH and instead set JAVA_HOME only.

Answer (score 2):

`JAVA_HOME` should be

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34`

and not

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin`

Answer (score 1):

FlashDevelop currently doesn't support that your JAVA_HOME environment var contains several paths (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\java.exe, \bin\java.exe).

Modify it to only indicate the first path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\java.exe).

Answer (score 0):

As someone who was dealing with this, I just found an answer that doesn't involve mucking with the PATH variables.

Go into your Flex SDK, /bin directory, look for the JVM config file conveniently named *jvm.config*

Inside, there is a param 'java.home' which, if left empty, will cause it to search for it's own value. Enter in the main path to the JRE - in my case,

```
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\
```

I found mine by going to "Control Panel > Java > Java tab > View... button" to see all the installed versions and their paths

I prefer this method because I feel like you shouldn't have to modify settings on your whole system to get 1 program to work, if you have the option instead to just modify that program's settings.

Answer (score 0):

jvm.config in C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\jvm.config is much more better than path variable.
Please avoid Path variable. 
In jvm.config just set  jre URL directory
   java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07

Answer (score -1):

May be you update the Java, last version of Java ask you to delete older version. Then go into the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\jvm.config
```

and replace

```
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\
```

by the folder were is your new version

```
java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\
```